# Dynamically set value to a record without a $FlowFixMe

Tags: flowtype, immutable.js

I have code that looks similar to this

```
const attr = event.target.value;
const query = filter.merge({
  [attr]: !filter[attr]
});
```

where `filter` is a Immutable Record. Flow complains *because an index signature declaring the expected key / value type is missing*.
Can I somehow tell flow that this is OK or do I have use a $FlowFixMe?
I'm using Immutable v4.0.0-rc.14

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using a switch statement

```
  switch(attr) {
    case "something":
      const query = filter.merge({
        something: !filter.something
      });
      break;
    case etc...
```